# Is it allowed to copy content from SharePoint.SE to another site?

Tags: discussion

On google I find this,

http://prabakaran3389.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/passing-argument-between-modal-popup.html

someone copied all of SharePoint exchange answer and made a blog post.

Comment: Vague question titles like yours are typically not allowed. Sorry for being so blunt :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Intellectual property have the shelf life of a banana" -*Bill Gates*

It is referenced here, so I would imagine this is OK. This is the same thing as we do here (from other sites), even if we often describe it in our own words and add a source link. Very much the same as academia does - build on others content an conclusion.

User content is licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for pointing this out! Copying/distributing/republishing the user-contributed content from SharePoint SE (or any other Stack Exchange site) for any purpose is perfectly fine, as long as [a few rules](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#3SubscriberContent) are followed:

- indicate the origin site and link back to the original post
- indicate the author's name and link to author's profile
- don't use `nofollow` or any other obfuscation while doing the above

For more info, see [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers).